# Files array validation in Liferay

Tags: java, file, liferay

How to validate files array? To check if there are file(s) in it or not.

```
File[] filess = uploadPortletRequest.getFiles("uploadFile");

System.out.println("file lenfth" + filess.length);

if (Validator.isNotNull(filess)) {
    System.out.println("cmoning inside");
}

if (filess.length > 0) {
    System.out.println("cmoning inside");
}
```

Comment: You can iterate through the array.

Comment: If file  is not is attached.. even though length array is 1. if iterate it will through null pointer exception.

Comment: Why will there be null pointer exception? If the file is not attached, why will the length of the array be 1?

Comment: Just iterate through array and use try catch. If you catch FileNotFoundException, then the file is not present and if you don't catch it, then the file is present there

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

i. Check, array is not null and has length using `!ArrayUtil.isEmpty(files)`. 
ii. Iterate through array and null check each file, as following:

```
File[] files = uploadPortletRequest.getFiles("uploadFile");

if (!ArrayUtil.isEmpty(files)) {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (Validator.isNotNull(file)) {
            // Do your processing on file object
        }
    }
}
```

Checking length of the `byte[]` of each file will be additional check to further avoid empty files.